# Understanding Unity's GameObject.Find(), GetComponent() and objects recycling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pool, particle-system

New to unity.

So I created a simple a simple muzzle flash particle animation that is supposed to be displayed on enemies gun when the player gets close to him, simulating a shot without the actual bullet. However I get a null reference exception in this part `muzzleFlash.Play();` I believe it's because I am not actually getting the muzzle flash component in the start function with the code I have, actually I know that is it after going to in to debug mode I found out. I am having a really hard time figuring out how to access that component. Below is my code and I'm also posting a picture of my hierarchy. Thanks in advance.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StaticShootingEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private float _range = 12f;
    private Transform _player;

    private bool _alive;
    private float _distance;
    private ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
        _alive = true;
        muzzleFlash = (ParticleSystem)this.gameObject.GetComponent("muzzleFLash");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        _distance = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, _player.transform.position);
        if (_alive && _distance < _range)
            AttackPlayer();
    }


    private void AttackPlayer()
    {
        //Turning enemy to look at player
        transform.LookAt(_player);
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, 0.75f, out hit))
        {
            //TODO: Fix enemy shooting fast when gettting close to him.
            GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
            if (hitObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>())
            {
                muzzleFlash.Play();
                Debug.Log("Player Hit!");
            }
            else
                muzzleFlash.Stop();
        }
    }

    public void SetAlive(bool alive)
    {
        _alive = alive;
    }

}
```

[image: Hierarchy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an object "muzzleFlash" as child to object your script attached to. So, in this case you'd better have a reference to your ParticleSystem object that is called muzzleFlash.

```
[SerializeField] private ParticleSystem muzzleFlash; // drag and drop your ParticleSystem muzzleFlash in inspector
```

or at least you could find that muzzleFlash like this

`GameObject muzzleFlashObj = GameObject.Find("muzzleFlash");
 ParticleSystem muzzleFlash = muzzleFlashObj.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();`

In your case it's null because there is probably no component that is called MuzzleFlash on that object. The component you want to get is ParticleSystem.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed I misspelled it but it still would not work. You are also right `StaticShootingEnemy` script is attached to mutant2 component and muzzleFlash is also in mutant2 but several levels deeper. I will be spanwning several mutant2's and want them all to have their own instance of muzzleFlash so that when I set one off the others don't go off as well. That's why I wanted to avoid `GameObject.Find`  or `GameObject.FindBytag` any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Also,If I drag and drop muzzleFlash to inspector and instantiate it on script, would it keep it's positioning at the barrel of the gun? I set the positioning manually by simply attaching to end of the barrel since the position of the barrel is always changing.

Comment: If i would do this, i'd not keep an instance of muzzleFlash effect for every mutant. Do they firing all the time simultaneously? - I highly doubt it. So, in this case you can implement a little effects pool. Something like i'll write in a sec in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

What component is the staticshootingenemy script on?  if it is not on the same component as the particle system then its not finding it because this.gameObject.GetComponent("muzzleFLash") does not exist on that component.  You can use GameObject.Find("muzzleFLash") to search for the particle system.

Comment: Yes, you are correct `StaticShootingEnemy` is attached to mutant2 and muzzleFlash is also in mutant2 but several levels down. I wanted to avoid `GameObject.Find` and `GameObject.FindbyTag` because I will be spawning several mutant2's and I wanted them all of them to have their instance of muzzleFlash so that if you set one on the others don't go on as well. Any ideas on how to  do this?

Comment: Try making the muzzleFlash particlesystem public instead of private and then drag the actual muzzleflash particle system into the muzzleflash slot of the script in the inspector.  Then if you spawn additional mutant2's the particle sysetm will always refer to their own.

Answer (score 1):

So back to your comment, you could implement something like a pool for your muzzle flashes.

```
public class MuzzleFlashEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem particleEffect;
    private Queue<MuzzleFlashEffect> poolQueue;

    public void SetPoolQueue(Queue<MuzzleFlashEffect> queue)
    {
        poolQueue = queue;
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Playing());
    }

    private IEnumerator Playing()
    {
        particleEffect.Play();

        while (particleEffect.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null; // wait until particle animation is done, then recycle effect
        }

        particleEffect.Stop();
        poolQueue.Enqueue(this);  // recycle this effect
    }

    // you can do the same thing for Animation as well, or even write some abstract PoolableVFX class that would be usefull for Animation , ParticleSystems etc.. 
}

//assume you have some game controller that manage what is going on in the scene
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MuzzleFlashEffect muzzleFlashPrefab;
    private Queue<MuzzleFlashEffect> poolQueue = new Queue<MuzzleFlashEffect>(10); // 10 is enough i guess and it's good to set it at instantiation to avoid memory fragmentation

    private MuzzleFlashEffect GetMuzzleFlash(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot)
    {
        MuzzleFlashEffect muzzleFlash;

        // if we already have some effects, then play them, otherwise make a new one and recycle it then
        if (poolQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            muzzleFlash = poolQueue.Dequeue();
        }
        else
        {
            muzzleFlash = Instantiate(muzzleFlashPrefab);
            muzzleFlash.SetPoolQueue(poolQueue);
        }

        muzzleFlash.transform.position = pos;
        muzzleFlash.transform.rotation = rot;

        return muzzleFlash;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // your fancy logic ...


        GameObject mutantGunEnd = new GameObject("mutant");
        //assume that here you want your muzzle flash effect, so you do:

        var muzzleFlash = GetMuzzleFlash(mutantGunEnd.transform.position, mutantGunEnd.transform.rotation); // or you might want to pass mutantGunEnd.transform.forward instead, it depends... 
        muzzleFlash.Play();


        // your fancy logic ...
    }
}
```

So, in this case you have only as many instance of ParticleEffect as you need and saving some resources. You could also create a universal generic pool for any type of object you want to recycle. (you want to recycle instead of instantiation, cuz Instantiation is cpu expensive).
M.b this is a bit overkill here, but i just wanted to share how would i think about this here

Comment: This is awesome a little a above my paygrade atm but I understand the concepts. I am little concern about the particle muzzleFlash showing up in the right spot when using a pool or drag and drop. Would you have to set the right position at the end of gun barrel via code? Are you doing this somewhere?

Comment: Actually I see it where you did that.

Comment: Btw.. i think it actually what you need, since with this design you able to do burst fire, which is fairly awkward if you have your effects and projectiles as child objects in a monster prefab.